# $X_1$, $X_2$ independent implies $e^{tX_1}$, $e^{tX_2}$ independent

Tags: statistics

Suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are continuous and independent random variables. How can I **prove** that $e^{tX_1}$ and $e^{tX_2}$ are independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $Y_i = e^{tX_i}$, and define $f(x) = e^{tx}$. For any $A_1, A_2$, we have
\begin{align*}
P(Y_1\in A_1, Y_1\in A_2) &= P(X_1\in f^{-1}A_1, X_2\in f^{-1}A_2) \\
&= P(X_1\in f^{-1}A_1)P(X_2\in f^{-1}A_2) \\
&= P(Y_1\in A_1)P(Y_2\in A_2),
\end{align*}
since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. Hence $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are also independent. (It may be worth noting that since $f$ is continuous, it is measurable for the usual Borel $\sigma$-algebra.)

Comment: Absolutely wonderful. All of these answers are useful. Haven't got to the Jacobian yet, but it lies here to help me when I get there. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you haven't done any study on "rigorous" probability theory. If I'm wrong, follow the other solutions. Otherwise, look at this one.

If $X_1$, $X_2$ are independent, then $f_{X_1, X_2}(x_1, x_2) = f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)$ for all $x_1, x_2$ over the support.

Suppose $Z_1 = e^{tX_1}$ and $Z_2 = e^{tX_2}$. Let's try to show that $f_{Z_1, Z_2}(z_1, z_2) = f_{Z_1}(z_1)f_{Z_2}(z_2)$.

By the Jacobian transformation method, we know that Jacobian is given by

$$J = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z_1}\left[\ln(z_1)/t\right]\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z_2}\left[\ln(z_2)/t\right] - (0)(0) = \dfrac{1}{z_1z_2t^2}\text{,}$$
and furthermore,
$$f_{Z_1, Z_2}(z_1, z_2) = \dfrac{f_{X_1, X_2}(\ln(z_1)/t, \ln(z_2)/t)}{z_1z_2t^2}\text{.}$$
By independence,
$$f_{Z_1, Z_2}(z_1, z_2) = \dfrac{f_{X_1}(\ln(z_1)/t)f_{X_2}(\ln(z_2)/t)}{z_1z_2t^2}\text{.}$$
Furthermore,
$$f_{Z_1}(z_1) = f_{X_1}(\ln(z_1)/t)\cdot \left|\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}z_1}\left[\ln(z_1)/t\right]\right| = \dfrac{f_{X_1}(\ln(z_1)/t)}{tz_1}\text{.}$$
Similarly,
$$f_{Z_2}(z_2) = f_{X_2}(\ln(z_2)/t)\cdot \left|\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}z_2}\left[\ln(z_2)/t\right]\right| = \dfrac{f_{X_2}(\ln(z_2)/t)}{tz_2}\text{.}$$
Hence $f_{Z_1, Z_2}(z_1, z_2) = f_{Z_1}(z_1)f_{Z_2}(z_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can show that functions of independent random variables are independent.

Let $X_1, X_2$ be independent.

$P(f(X_1) \in A, g(X_2) \in B) = P( X_1 \in f^{-1}(A) , X_2 \in g^{-1}(B) ) = P(X_1 \in f^{-1}(A)) P(X_2 \in g^{-1}(B)) = P (f(X_1) \in A) P(g(X_2) \in B)$.

Thus, $f(X_1), g(X_2)$ are indepndent.

Comment: This (looks) like a valid proof to me, but just judging by what kind of question this is, I'm willing to bet that they want a proof showing that $f_{e^{X_1}, e^{X_2}}(s, t) = f_{e^{X_1}}(s)f_{e^{X_2}}(t)$.

Comment: This is using just the definition of independence of random variables -- It would be hard to give a more elementary proof (if even possible). I suppose I should note that everything is appropriately measurable (what should be measurable where is obvious).